# Store line renderer's all points as a object in XML file

Tags: unity-game-engine, xml-serialization

I am facing a problem while storing Line Renderer's all point as a single object in XML file. What I am trying to do is draw something in the air using line renderer and store that drawing as a points in XML file to recreate it. I am able to save everything properly except every point is becoming a single object instead of generating under a single object. Below is my code:

### AirDrawObject.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]
public class AirDrawObject
{
    public string pointIndex;
    public Vector3 pointPosition;
}
```

### XMLDataExporter.cs

```
public AirDrawObject newAirDrawObject;
public ObjectDatabase objectDB;

public void SaveFeedback(GameObject parentGameObject)
    {
        Transform[] childObjects = parentGameObject.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
         if (childObjects[i].gameObject.tag == "AirDraw")
            {
                LineRenderer lineRenderer = childObjects[i].gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
                int count = lineRenderer.positionCount;
                int[] array = new int[count];
                for (int l = 0; l < array.Length; l++)
                {
                    newAirDrawObject = new AirDrawObject();
                    newAirDrawObject.pointIndex = "Point " + l.ToString();
                    newAirDrawObject.pointPosition = lineRenderer.GetPosition(l);
                    objectDB.airDrawObjectList.Add(newAirDrawObject);
                }
            }
     }
```

### XML File:

```
<airDrawObjectList>
    <AirDrawObject>
      <point>Point 0</point>
      <pointPosition>
        <x>-0.0537847765</x>
        <y>0.03524115</y>
        <z>0.518784344</z>
      </pointPosition>
    </AirDrawObject>
    <AirDrawObject>
      <point>Point 1</point>
      <pointPosition>
        <x>-0.0537847765</x>
        <y>0.03524115</y>
        <z>0.518784344</z>
      </pointPosition>
    </AirDrawObject>
    <AirDrawObject>
      <point>Point 2</point>
      <pointPosition>
        <x>-0.0537847765</x>
        <y>0.03524115</y>
        <z>0.518784344</z>
      </pointPosition>
    </AirDrawObject>
```

---

### Expected Result:

```
 <AirDrawObject>
  <point>Point 1</point>
   <pointPosition>
     <x>-0.0537847765</x>
     <y>0.03524115</y>
     <z>0.518784344</z>
   </pointPosition>
  <point>Point 2</point>
  <pointPosition>
    <x>-0.0537847765</x>
    <y>0.03524115</y>
    <z>0.518784344</z>
  </pointPosition>
  <point>Point 3</point>
  <point>Point 4</point>
 </AirDrawObject>
<AirDrawObject>
  ....
</AirDrawObject>
```

---

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well .. you are creating single objects in a list ... what exactly is your goal? How else would you want to store it?

Comment: @derHugo..I want to store all points of one line renderer object in list instead of separate objects.. I know it might be silly mistake but I am able to figure it out. I have put expected result also, so kindly check it

Comment: Makes no sense the way you posted it .. you open the `<point>` tag but you close it already before providing the position .. so it would be a list of alternating `point` and `pointPosition` objects ...

Comment: Ohh..sorry for that. But that <point> is just a string which stores the index.

Comment: I just wat to store the positions of all the points under one object only..that's the thing I want to achieve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply make your class

```c#
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("ObjectDatabase")]
public class ObjectDatabase
{
    [XmlArray("AirDrawList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("AirDraw")]
    public List<XmlAirDraw> AirDrawList = new List<XmlAirDraw>();
}

[Serializable]
public class XmlAirDraw
{
    [XmlArray("points")]
    [XmlArrayItem("point")]
    public List<Vector3> points = new List<Vector3>();
}
```

And then rather save like

```c#
public void SaveFeedback(GameObject parentGameObject)
{
    objectDb.AirDrawList.Clear();      

    var lines = parentGameObject.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<LineRenderer>(true);

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if(!line.CompareTag("AirDraw")) continue;

        line.GetPositions(out var linePoints);
        var xmlInstance = new AirDrawInstance
        {
            points = linePoints;
        };  

        objectDb.AirDrawList.Add(newAirDrawObject);
     }
 }
```

---

Note that I'm typing on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear and this should generate XML like

```xml
<ObjectDataBase>
    <AirDrawList>
        <AirDraw>
            <points>
                <point>
                   <x>-0.0537847765</x>
                   <y>0.03524115</y>
                   <z>0.518784344</z>
                </point>
                <point>
                    <x>-0.0537847765</x>
                    <y>0.03524115</y>
                    <z>0.518784344</z>
                </point> 
                ...   
            </points>
        </AirDraw>
        <AirDraw>  
            <points>
                ...   
            </points>
        </AirDraw> 
        ...   
    </AirDrawList>
</ObjectDataBase>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did it somewhat like this. Let me post my version.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out by myself. I have changed my class for point and airDrawPoint like below.

AirDrawPoint.cs

```
[System.Serializable]
public class AirDrawPoint
{
    public string index;
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;
}
```

AirDrawObject.cs

```
[System.Serializable]

public class AirDrawObject
{
    public List<AirDrawPoint> pointList = new List<AirDrawPoint>();
}
```

XMLDataExporter.cs

```
if (childObjects[i].gameObject.tag == "AirDraw")
            {
                newAirDrawObject = new AirDrawObject();
                LineRenderer lineRenderer = childObjects[i].gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
                int count = lineRenderer.positionCount;
                int[] array = new int[count];
                for (int l = 0; l < array.Length; l++)
                {
                    point = new AirDrawPoint();
                    Vector3 position = lineRenderer.GetPosition(l);
                    point.index = "Point " + l.ToString();
                    point.X = position.x;
                    point.Y = position.y;
                    point.Z = position.z;
                    newAirDrawObject.pointList.Add(point);
                }
                objectDB.airDrawObjectList.Add(newAirDrawObject);
            }
```